# Workers and food problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A team of $30$ men can do work in $38$ days. After $25$ days, $5$ more men were employed and work finished $1$ day earlier. For how many days would it have been delayed if $5$ more men aren't employed.

How do i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't totally make sense (unless they meant to give the answer)...if they finished 1 day earlier, clearly the work would have been delayed 1 day if they hadn't hired the $5$ extra men...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$30$ men do a job in $38$ days, so one man would take $30 \cdot 38 = 1140$ days to do the job (in other words, one man can do $\frac{1}{1140}$ of the job in one day).

This is how you should start a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the statement is not good but I wonder what you mean (I think...).

You are considering that the total work was made in 37 days. 25 days with 30 men and 12 days with 35 men. Let's call $T$ the total work and $k$ (amount of work/day) the work force of each man.

So,

$$25.30.k+12.35.k=T \rightarrow k= \frac{T}{25.30+12.35}$$

If they didn't hire 5 guys it will take a number of days $t$ given by:

$$30.k.t=T \rightarrow 30.\frac{T}{25.30+12.35}.t= T \rightarrow t= 39$$

And then the work will take $1$ day more.